# Why is VS Code Java debugger looking for a JAR file for a dependency that does not exist?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, debugging

I have the Java extension pack for VS Code installed as well as Red Hat Java language support extention. Every time I try to `run and debug` right away I get the error message `Exception has occurred: java.io.FileNotFoundException "java.io.FileNotFoundException: \C:\Users\myUserName\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar"`. When I go looking for this file in my local drive it is  missing but when attempting to install it from [maven central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/) it also does not appear to exist.

**What I have tried:**

1. installing it from maven central - the file does not exist there either
2. making my own blank file with the required name - I get another error referring to null zip
3. A ton of different debug `launch` configurations all with the same exception being thrown

**Below is my current `launch.json` file:**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Launch Current File",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "${file}"
    },
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "myAppName",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "com.name.myAppName"
    },
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "myAppName",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "com.name.myAppName",
        "projectName": "projectName",
        "vmArgs": "-DAPP_NAME=myAppName -DAPP_FILE_LOG=true -DAPP_CONSOLE_LOG=true" //    <----- this enables the logging, others need it on too and launch using the GUI
    },
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Spring Boot-myAppName",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "mainClass": "com.name.myAppName",
        "projectName": "projectName",
        "args": "",
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
    }
]
```

}

**Note: I have tried launching numerous ways such as GUI, command palette, right clicking on main file, etc.**

**launching the application without debugging works just fine**

**What should I do to fix this? I figure I either need the file or a way for the debugger to stop looking for this file**

Comment: Side note I have forgotten to mention is that I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension multiple times.

Comment: Use `mvn clean install` to clean up and rebuild the project, update the dependency items in pom.xml, and restart the vscode or refresh the Maven option.

Comment: @JialeDu Unfortunately this only gave the same results, I tried it several times too.